# How to export links (url's) or other data from specific iPhone chat?

Tags: command-line, messages, sqlite

I recently learned how to use sqlite3 in the command line to export a .csv of url's from my icloud_tabs.db

I would like to do something similar with a specific iPhone chat. I use Messages as storage for links, quotes, documents, and other data while I work. So I have a chat with myself where I send myself these notes.

I would like to use the terminal to export all of this data from this one specific Messages chat (as far back as possible). Even better if I can get more granular and export just url's, or just images of a certain file type, or just PDFs (etc.)

Any insight is much appreciated, ty!

Comment: *"Any insight is much appreciated, ty!"* where are you stuck ? finding the location of chat files? the commands to run ?

Comment: @anki I am a total noob and I am not a coder/developer. I am looking for the commands to run. The database seemed relatively straightforward for icloud_tabs.db, with devices clearly labeled with a UUID but the ~Library/Messages/Chat.db seems to be quite a bit more complex. When I tried to output its entire contents to a csv it's messy and I'm not sure what I'm looking at really. I've tried to learn more about sqlite3 and I used the dot commands such as .table to take a better look at the Chat.db but I am still not sure where to find attachments like urls or how to isolate a specific chat.